# Silent app install on supervised IOS device with MDM server

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-vpp

Is it possible to Silently Remote install AppStore app on ios using mdm api without using VPP.
The device is in supervised mode

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS7 all normal app installs are silent on supervised devices when executed with MDM.

Comment: are you sure ? according to my tests when I install an app ( itunes free app ) from the mdm server on ios9 supervised devices, a confirm dialog pops up ( without VPP ).
maybe there is some plist property I need to add ?

Comment: @Jacob, come to think about it, this was for enterprise apps, not store ones. My apologies.